# Ninject Transient Scope + Scope Disposal + Garbage Collection + Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I am new at this (I'm still learning), I would appreciate very much if you Jedi masters out there can help me out with the question and concern that I have.

I want to use Ninject and I have the codes below, I would like to know whether my objects will get disposed properly and garbage collected.

For Ninject's default Transient Scope, I read that "Lifetime is not managed by the Kernel (the Scope object is null) and will never be Disposed."

If I would to use my codes in production, especially when I get lots of concurrent calls to my WebApi (POST), will it cause any problems like Memory Leak, etc?

What would be the best Ninject's Object scope to use for this situation?

By the way, if I don't specify the object scope like "kernel.Bind().To();", will it default to TransientScope?

```
public class VehicleClassRepository : IVehicleClassRepository
{
    SomeDataContext context = new SomeDataContext();

    public IQueryable<VehicleClass> All
    {
        get { return context.VehicleClasses; }
    }

    public IQueryable<VehicleClass> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<VehicleClass, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<VehicleClass> query = context.VehicleClasses;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public VehicleClass Find(int id)
    {
        return context.VehicleClasses.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(VehicleClass vehicleclass)
    {
        if (vehicleclass.VehicleClassId == default(int)) {
            // New entity
            context.VehicleClasses.Add(vehicleclass);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Entry(vehicleclass).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var vehicleclass = context.VehicleClasses.Find(id);
        context.VehicleClasses.Remove(vehicleclass);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IVehicleClassRepository : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<VehicleClass> All { get; }
    IQueryable<VehicleClass> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<VehicleClass, object>>[] includeProperties);
    VehicleClass Find(int id);
    void InsertOrUpdate(VehicleClass vehicleclass);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Save();
}
```

In my NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IVehicleClassRepository>().To<VehicleClassRepository>();
    }
```

In my WebApi's VehicleClassController.cs:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(VehicleClass value)
{
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        else
        {
            vehicleclassRepository.InsertOrUpdate(value);
            vehicleclassRepository.Save();
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in case you don't specify a scope, it defaults to transient scope.

Transient scope means that ninject does not keep a reference to the created object. It will get garbage collected by the GC as soon as you don't keep a reference to it any longer.

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit: Thank you for the clarification... If it doesn't keep a reference to the created object... my codes above should be safe from memory leak then? Would it be better to use InRequestScope?

Comment: Yeah unless you keep a reference longer than needed, Transient scope means there's not going to be a memory leak.

Comment: Regarding the InRequestScope: You only need that (or any other scope like InSingleton, NamedScope, ParentScope...) if you want to get the same Instance of ISomething injected into 2+ objects belonging to the same object. AND/OR in case you want ninject to manage ISomethings lifecycle (i.E. dispose it). InRequestScope means that Ninject will call ISomething.Dispose() as soon as the Request Scope is disposed (request ends).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Web MVC and the InRequestScope extension specifically so i can't answer more concrete questions about that.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer (almost 2 years) but in case others read this...

Although it's true that the garbage collector will eventually dispose of your VehicleClassRepository instance, you'll very likely run into problems before then.

Your data context likely holds an open db connection until it's disposed.  The db connection probably comes from a pool of db connections.

So long before the CLR ends up garbage collecting these (which would also dispose them), incoming requests end up blocking while trying to get a db connection but there are none available.

I've encountered this type of behavior and learned from it the hard way.  So the VehicleClassRepository should be scoped in dependency scope so that you get one per call and more importantly, it'll get disposed immediately after the call is done.